# Laravel 5.6 - Async / Lazy load vue components with laravel-mix and webpack

Tags: laravel, vue.js, lazy-loading, vue-router, laravel-mix

```
Laravel 5.6.21
NPM 6.1.0
Node 10.5.0
Webpack 3.12.0
```

My question is how to properly configure laravel-mix, webpack and babel to successfully lazy-load vue components using the method described here: [Lazying Loading Routes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html#grouping-components-in-the-same-chunk)

More specifically, using stage-2 (es2018 ?) syntax as follows:

```
const Foo = () => import('./Foo.vue')
```

When trying to compile using laravel-mix all statements resembling the above syntax generate an error (example):

```
 Syntax Error: Unexpected token (1:24)

 1 | const Dashboard = () => import("Pages/Account/Dashboard.vue");

   |                         ^
```

I believe laravel-mix uses Babel to transpile and read that Babel needs 'syntax-dynamic-import' so I created a .bablerc file with the following contents:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "syntax-dynamic-import"
  ]
}
```

Since the bable config file didn't resolve the issue, I also tried an eslint configuration file with the following contents:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: ["vue"], // enable vue plugin
  extends: ["plugin:vue/recommended", "prettier"], // activate vue related rules
  parserOptions: {
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "ecmaVersion": 7,  //also tried 8
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "globalReturn": false,
      "impliedStrict": false,
      "jsx": false,
      "experimentalObjectRestSpread": false,
      "allowImportExportEverywhere": false
    }
  }
};
```

Finally, a copy of the dependencies in package.json are:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.24",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-imports": "^1.5.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-vue-app": "^2.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^2.9.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^4.5.0",
    "expect": "^22.0.3",
    "jsdom": "^11.5.1",
    "jsdom-global": "^3.0.2",
    "laravel-mix": "^2.1.14",
    "less": "^3.5.3",
    "less-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "mocha": "^4.0.1",
    "mocha-webpack": "^1.0.1",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-loader": "^13.7.2",
    "vue-style-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.13",
    "vue-test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.8",
    "webpack": "^3.12.0",
    "webpack-auto-inject-version": "^1.1.0"
  },
```

Any help regarding resolving this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using with following in `.eslintrc.json`.

```
"extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:vue/recommended"
],
"plugins": [
    "vue"
],
"parser": "vue-eslint-parser",
"parserOptions": {
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "ecmaVersion": 8,
    "ecmaFeatures": {
        "jsx": true
    },
    "sourceType": "module"
},
```

Also check your dynamic import function's path `const Dashboard = () => import("Pages/Account/Dashboard.vue");`. I thinks it should be a relative path something like `const Dashboard = () => import("./Pages/Account/Dashboard.vue");`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `scss splitting` in Vue  and using `mix.scss()` both. Laravel mix when having both creates a `css` file with manifest js file content in it. which is definitely a bug. which the community mentions a bug from Webpack and will be resolved in webpack 5. But If you use only code splitting in Vue and have the default `app.scss` file imported to main Vue component like this(not in scope), so each other component will get the styling properly

```
// resources/js/components/app.vue
<template>
 <!-- Main Vue Component  -->
</template>

<script>
// Main Script
</script>

<style lang="scss">
  @import '~@/sass/app.scss';
</style>
```

and the `webpack.mix.js` file will have no `mix.scss` function to run only a single app.js file. here is my file.

```js
// webpack.mix.js
const mix = require('laravel-mix')
mix.babelConfig({
  plugins: ['@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import'] // important to install -D
})

mix.config.webpackConfig.output = {
  chunkFilename: 'js/[name].bundle.js',
  publicPath: '/'
}

mix
  .js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
  .extract(['vue'])
  .webpackConfig({
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '@': path.resolve('resources/') // just to use relative path properly
      }
    }
  })
```

here is the `package.json` file (only including required dev dependencies)

```
{
       "@babel/core": "^7.8.7",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.7",
        "laravel-mix": "^4.1.4",
}
```

hope this resolves the issue